# Storing words from a .txt file into a String array

Tags: java, arrays, string

I was going through the answers of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28643680/java-storing-each-word-from-an-input-file-in-an-array-of-strings) question asked by someone previously and I found them to be very helpful. However, I have a question about the [highlighted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28643748/14585560) answer but I wasn't sure if I should ask there since it's a 6 year old thread.

My question is about this snippet of code given in the answers:

```
private static boolean isAWord(String token)
{
    //check if the token is a word
}
```

How *would* you check that the token is a word? Would you `.contains("\\s+")` the string and check to see if it contains characters between them? But what about when you encounter a paragraph? I'm not sure how to go about this.

EDIT: I think I should've elaborated a bit more. Usually, you'd think a word would be something surrounded by " " but, for example, if the file contains a hyphen (which is also surrounded by a blank space), you'd want the `isAWord()` method to return false. How can I verify that something is actually a word and not punctuation?

Comment: Hm, that depends on the definition of "word" I think. Maybe `token.matches("\\w+")` If the word is supposed to contain letters only `token.matches("[A-Za-z]+")` But that won't match umlauts and other non ASCII letters

Answer (score 1):

Since the question wasn't entirely clear, I made two methods. First method consistsOfLetters just goes through the whole string and returns false if it has any numbers/symbols. This should be enough to determine if a token is word (if you don't mind if that words exists in dictionary or not).

```
public static boolean consistsOfLetters(String string) {
        for(int i=0; i<string.length(); i++) {
            if(string.charAt(i) == '.' && (i+1) == string.length() && string.length() != 1) break; // if last char of string is ., it is still word
            if((string.toLowerCase().charAt(i) < 'a' || string.toLowerCase().charAt(i) > 'z')) return false; 
        }  // toLowerCase is used to avoid having to compare it to A and Z
        return true;
    }
```

Second method helps us divide original String (for example a sentence of potentional words) based on " " character. When that is done, we go through every element there and check if it is a word. If it's not a word it returns false and skips the rest. If everything is fine, returns true.

```
    public static boolean isThisAWord(String string) {
        String[] array = string.split(" ");
        for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            if(consistsOfLetters(array[i]) == false) return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Also, this might not work for English since English has apostrophes in words like "don't" so a bit of further tinkering is needed.

Answer (score 0):

The Scanner in java splits string using his `WHITESPACE_PATTERN` by default, so splitting a string like `"He's my friend"` would result in an array like `["He's", "my", "friend"]`.
If that is sufficient, just remove that if clause and dont use that method.
If you want to make it to `"He","is"` instead of `"He's"`, you need a different approach.

In short: The method works like verification check -> if the given token is not supposed to be in the result, then return false, true otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

```
return token.matches("[\\pL\\pM]+('(s|nt))?");
```

`matches` requires the entire string to match.

This takes letters `\pL` and zero-length combining diacritical marks `\pM` (accents).
And possibly for English apostrophe, should you consider `doesn't` and `let's` *one* term (for instance for translation purposes).
You might also consider hyphens.

*There are several single quotes and dashes.*

```
Path path = Paths.get("..../x.txt");
Charset charset = Charset.defaultCharset();
String content = Files.readString(path, charset)
Pattern wordPattern = Pattern.compile("[\\pL\\pM]+");
Matcher m = wordPattern.matcher(content);
while (m.find()) {
    String word = m.group(); ...
}
```